# Error: The operation completed successfully (Command Line Game Engine in C++ using Windows API)

Tags: c++, windows

As described in the title I want to write a game engine using the command line console. Following closely the project of oneLoneCoder, the code that I have written so far is the following. It creates a command console after it checks that the dimensions given by the user are correct.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

namespace CmdLineConsoleEngine {

    void Error(const HANDLE& hConsole, const wchar_t* msg) {
    
        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 256, NULL);
        SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
        wprintf(L"ERROR: %s\n\t%s\n", msg, buf);
        exit(-1);
    }

    auto CreateConsole() -> HANDLE {

        HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
        if (hConsole == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            Error(hConsole, L"Bad Handle"); // in which cases does this occur?
        else {
            SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
        }
        return hConsole;
    }

    void CheckConsoleSize(const HANDLE& hConsole, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {

        assert(hConsole != nullptr);
        assert(screenWidth > 0);
        assert(screenHeight > 0);

        const COORD largestSize = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(hConsole);
        if (screenWidth > largestSize.X) 
            Error(hConsole, L"The width dimension is too large.");
        if (screenHeight > largestSize.Y) 
            Error(hConsole, L"The height dimension is too large.");
        return;
    }

    void SetConsoleWindowSize(HANDLE& hConsole, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {

        CheckConsoleSize(hConsole, screenWidth, screenHeight);

        const SMALL_RECT minimalRectWindow = { 0, 0, 12, 6 };
        SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &minimalRectWindow);

        COORD coord = {static_cast<short>(screenWidth), static_cast<short>(screenHeight)};
        if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConsole, coord))
            Error(hConsole, L"SetConsoleScreenBufferSize");

        SMALL_RECT rectWindow = {0, 0, static_cast<short>(screenWidth - 1), static_cast<short>(screenHeight - 1)};
        if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &rectWindow))
            Error(hConsole, L"SetConsoleWindowInfo");
        return;
    }

    void WriteToConsole(const HANDLE& hConsole, const wchar_t* screen, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {

        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, screenWidth * screenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
    }

}

int main() {

    HANDLE hConsole = CmdLineConsoleEngine::CreateConsole();
    int screenWidth = 160;
    int screenHeight = 140;
    CmdLineConsoleEngine::SetConsoleWindowSize(hConsole, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    return 0;
}
```

Executing the `main()` function the output that I get is

```
ERROR: The height dimension is too large.
The operation completed successfully.
```

It is the `Error` function acting funny. For your convenience, the call hierarchy is `SetConsoleWindowSize -> CheckConsoleSize -> Error`

Any idea on why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error reporting in `CheckConsoleSize()` is wrong. `GetLastError()` is only meaningful if `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize()` returns a `COORD` containing all zeros, which you are not checking for. What you have described sounds like the `COORD` is simply containing sizes that are smaller than you are expecting, but are not zeros.  That is why `GetLastError()` is returning 0, and thus `FormatMessage()` is returning `"The operation completed successfully"`.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

namespace CmdLineConsoleEngine {

    void Error(HANDLE hConsole, const wchar_t* msg) {
        SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
        wprintf(L"ERROR: %s\n", msg);
        exit(-1);
    }

    void ErrorWithCode(HANDLE hConsole, const wchar_t* msg, DWORD ErrorCode = GetLastError()) {
        wchar_t buf[256] = {};
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, ErrorCode, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 256, NULL);
        SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
        wprintf(L"ERROR: %s\n\t%s\n", msg, buf);
        exit(-1);
    }

    HANDLE CreateConsole() {
        HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
        if (hConsole == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ErrorWithCode(hConsole, L"Bad Handle"); // in which cases does this occur?
        SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
        return hConsole;
    }

    void DestroyConsole(HANDLE& hConsole) {
        if (hConsole != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            CloseHandle(hConsole);
            hConsole = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }

    void CheckConsoleSize(HANDLE hConsole, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        assert(hConsole != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
        assert(screenWidth > 0);
        assert(screenHeight > 0);
        const COORD largestSize = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(hConsole);
        if (largestSize.X == 0 && largestSize.Y == 0) 
            ErrorWithCode(hConsole, L"GetLargestConsoleWindowSize");
        if (screenWidth > largestSize.X) 
            Error(hConsole, L"The width dimension is too large.");
        if (screenHeight > largestSize.Y) 
            Error(hConsole, L"The height dimension is too large.");
    }

    void SetConsoleWindowSize(HANDLE hConsole, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        CheckConsoleSize(hConsole, screenWidth, screenHeight);

        const SMALL_RECT minimalRectWindow = { 0, 0, 12, 6 };
        if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &minimalRectWindow))
            ErrorWithCode(hConsole, L"SetConsoleWindowInfo");

        COORD coord = {static_cast<short>(screenWidth), static_cast<short>(screenHeight)};
        if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConsole, coord))
            ErrorWithCode(hConsole, L"SetConsoleScreenBufferSize");

        SMALL_RECT rectWindow = {0, 0, static_cast<short>(screenWidth - 1), static_cast<short>(screenHeight - 1)};
        if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &rectWindow))
            ErrorWithCode(hConsole, L"SetConsoleWindowInfo");
    }

    void WriteToConsole(HANDLE hConsole, const wchar_t* screen, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
        if (!WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, screenWidth * screenHeight, {0, 0}, &dwBytesWritten))
            ErrorWithCode(hConsole, L"WriteConsoleOutputCharacter");
    }
}

int main() {
    HANDLE hConsole = CmdLineConsoleEngine::CreateConsole();
    CmdLineConsoleEngine::SetConsoleWindowSize(hConsole, 160, 140);
    CmdLineConsoleEngine::DestroyConsole(hConsole);
    return 0;
}
```

---

On a side note: calling `Error/WithCode()` if `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()` fails doesn't make sense, as you would be calling `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer()` with an invalid console handle.

Comment: But in which cases can the ```GetLargestConsoleWindowSize``` return a struct with zeros?
And also, when can the ```CreateConsole``` return a bad handle?

Comment: I might actually write a header file to handle the errors without using the windows API. Do you see any serious disadvantages about this?

Comment: @AngelosFr does it really matter? Even if they never fail in practice, you should still always write code to handle system errors properly.

Comment: And any advice on how to treat this case: 
```if (hConsole == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            ErrorWithCode(hConsole, L"Bad Handle"); ```
Write an error message to a different console (but what if creation fails)? Just exit and keep a comment?

Comment: @AngelosFr probably write to the default STDERR via `GetStdHandle()`, or maybe write to a log file, just something other than the console.